# Can't copy Centos 5.3 ISO to flashdrive?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a weird problem, I downloaded Centos 5.3 from the net and now need to copy it to my 64Gig Flash Drive with has 24Gig Free Space. Everytime I try to Copy it over it gives me error:

**CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-DVD.iso': File too large**

Centos 5.3 is 4.2Gig in size and it only copies 4Gig over to the flash drive

OS = Ubuntu 9.04

Why is my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, what file system is your USB formatted too?
If it is fat32 or fat16, there is a size limit of 4gig per file. Try compressing the ISO into multiple archive files and the copying them onto your USB drive and then extract later.

See [this page for more information](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm)

EDIT: Try formatting your USB to EXT3 and allow a file size of 16GB, if you don't mind losing all your data currently on your usb and it being accessible only from a *NIX system.

Comment: correct. You'll need another file system to copy it as one single file.

Comment: You meant, "try dividing the ISO into multiple archives files". Yes, I think his problem is the file system.

Comment: It's Fat 32 drive, is there any tool that would work great for this type of thing?

Comment: I see the Maximum File size is 4Gig

Comment: If you don't mind losing your data, open up or install GParted in ubuntu, then select your usb from the menu at top right and then format to EXT3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the file format is the only factor.  I encountered a similar problem copying a file which is 1.4 MB to a 32-MB FAT-16 partition of a 2-GB UFD.  I tried to copy it to the other partitions:  950-MB linux-swap partition and 890~-MB EXT4 partition.  In GParted I see key icons on both the EXT4 and FAT-16 partitions but NOT the 950-MB linux-swap partition.  I do not know if there is some password clearance required as I am running this procedure(attempt) from a Live Boot CD of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx.

EDIT:  Upon reboot I changed the FAT16 partition to FAT32 and was thus able to copy.
- T -